# jQueryUI and jQueryUI-touch-punch don't work with Polymer.dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-js-interop

I'm developing a small Dart app using jQueryUI and jQueryUI-touch-punch with Polymer.dart. When I don't use Polymer.dart, everything works well. But with Polymer.dart, several problems occurred. Here is my codes.

### index.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dart and jquery ui with Polymer</title>

  <!--- stylesheet --->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dart_and_jquery_ui_with_polymer.css">
  <!--- ---------- --->

  <!--- JSLib --->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="js/libs/jquery.ui.touch-punch-0.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <!--- ----- --->

  <link rel="import" href="main_component.html">
  <script type="application/dart">
  export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Dart and jquery ui with Polymer</h1>

  <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

  <!-- CUSTOM ELEMENT -->
  <main-component></main-component>

  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

### main_component.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<polymer-element name="main-component">
 <template>
  <div id="sample_container_id">
   <button id="btn1">OPEN JSVer</button>
   <button id="btn2">OPEN DartVer</button>

   <div id="msg1">
    Hello, world1!
    <div>
     <button>btn1</button>
     <button>btn2</button>
     <button>btn3</button>
     <button>btn4</button>
     <button>btn5</button>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="msg2">
    Hello, world2!
    <div>
     <button>btn1</button>
     <button>btn2</button>
     <button>btn3</button>
     <button>btn4</button>
     <button>btn5</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </template>

 <!-- JSScript -->
 <script src="js/js_main.js"></script>
 <!-- -------- -->

 <!-- DartScript -->
 <script type="application/dart" src="main_component.dart"></script>
 <!-- ---------- -->
</polymer-element>
```

### js/js_main.js

```dart
$( function(){

 // The code in this JS file totally doesn't work...
 // But there is no error message in JS console...

 // btn1 config
 $('#btn1').click( function() {
  $('#msg1').dialog('open');
 } );

 // msg1 config
 $('#msg1').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
   "OK": function() {
    $(this).dialog('close');
   }
  },
  title: "Dialog1",
  resizable: false,
  modal: false,
  show: 'fold',
  hide: 'puff'
 });

 // btn2 and msg2 configs are implemented in Dart side.
} );
```

### main_component.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:js' as js;

@CustomTag('main-component')
class MainComponent extends PolymerElement {

 MainComponent.created() : super.created(){
  // Constructor...
 }

 @override
 void attached(){
  super.attached();

  // btn2 config
  js.context.callMethod(r'$', [ $['btn2'] ])
   ..callMethod('click', [ 
    ([arg]){
     js.context.callMethod(r'$', [ $['msg2'] ])
      ..callMethod('dialog', ['open']);
    } 
  ]);

  // msg2 config
  js.JsObject options = new js.JsObject(js.context['Object']);
  options['autoOpen'] = false;
  options['buttons'] = new js.JsObject(js.context['Object']);
  options['buttons']['OK'] = ([arg]){ 
   js.context.callMethod(r'$', [ $['msg2'] ])
    ..callMethod('dialog', ['close']);
  };
  options['title'] = "Dialog2";
  options['modal'] = false;
  options['show'] = 'fold';
  options['hide'] = 'puff';
  js.context.callMethod(r'$', [ $['msg2'] ])
   ..callMethod('dialog', [options]);
 }
}
```

The problems are

1. msg1 doesn't form dialog and btn1 doesn't execute mouse click event I registered. This means JS scripts in "js_main.js" don't work (with NO error message). I found custom elements of Polymer.dart implement Shadow DOM which prohibit any access from outside. Is this the cause of the problem?
2. When I convert this Dart app into JavaScript using "pub build", the generated product can run in a browser of my iPad mini(iOS6). This is OK. However, it seems jQueryUI-touch-punch doesn't work well. So I cannot access any dragging or resizing action from my iPad mini.

Dart SDK version is 1.2.

Can anyone help?

Thanks for reading to the end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery element selection code `$('#msg')`, `$('#btnx')` wont find any element inside the shadowDOM. There might be other problems but this one is obvious.

Comment: I see. Does that mean there is no way to access into the element in ShadowDOM from JS?

Comment: That's not the case, you actually can access the ShadowDom from JS but jQuery can't do it by default. The problem is that it may be different on different browsers (native implementation/polyfill) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218123 .

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin 's solution might be a better approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586905. To select the element in Dart and pass the result to JavaScript.